# How to fix 'Bad Request (400)' error when POSTing JSON payload in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core

I am developing a razor page which implements a named handler method. I post some JSON encoded data to the named handler method. However, I get a 400 bad request response in response.

I have tried using different JSON payloads and different method signatures so far but alas, nothing has worked.

Here is a snub of my method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult OnPostContextFreeGrammarPartial() {
            var grammarModel = new ContextFreeGrammarModel();

            return new PartialViewResult() {
                ViewName = "_ContextFreeGrammar",
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<ContextFreeGrammarModel>(ViewData, grammarModel)
            };
        }
```

And here is an example request:

[image: The sent HTTP request]

I am expecting the handler method to be successfully executed but instead the server or browser simply throws a 400 response before the method even begins to execute.

What am I missing?

Comment: I am passing a payload to OnPostContextFreeGrammar but I don't know if ASP.NET Core methods can execute whilst ignoring the payload. Also ```grammarModel``` is not null.

Comment: Razor Pages aren't intended to do things like handle JSON requests like an API. You can probably get it to work, but it's going to require a disproportionate amount of effort. When it comes to stuff like this, you're better off with controllers. That said, if I had to take a guess, I'd say that anti-forgery validation is in effect, and you don't seem to be passing the token. That will always cause a 400. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.1#javascript-ajax-and-spas

Comment: Thank you for this comment. This was the solution. I had to add the anti-forgery token to the request header. I will investigate into using controllers instead of razor pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chris Pratt's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149116/how-to-fix-bad-request-400-error-when-posting-json-payload-in-asp-net-core?noredirect=1#comment98929279_56149116) explains the issue. The anti-forgery token was missing from the request header - which is required for post requests on Razor pages.

He also suggested using a Controller instead of a Razor page.

**EDIT**

Adding a `IgnoreAntiforgeryToken` filter to the services during startup also fixed the problem.

```
            services.AddMvc()
                .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
                    options.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
                }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass data to OnPostContextFreeGrammarPartial and I think `grammarModel` is null! Try this I think it's helpful [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-post-complex-JSON-d15bb765)

```
    [HttpPost]
[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
        public IActionResult OnPostContextFreeGrammarPartial([FromBody]ContextFreeGrammarModel item) 
        {
            var grammarModel = new ContextFreeGrammarModel();

            return new PartialViewResult() {
                ViewName = "_ContextFreeGrammar",
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<ContextFreeGrammarModel>(ViewData, grammarModel)
            };
        }
```

And also in startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
        });
```